# Что из себя представляет создание куба в OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

Правильно ли я понимаю что куб это 6 - 2d плоскостей которым программист вручную прописывает вращения что тем самым имитирует куб? или это не так?...
Смотрел этот туториал и понял что нет какой то определённой функции для работы 3х мерным пространством... а все надо делать вручную или как?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcMox6i8f4Y&t=685s

Answer (score 3):

вот вам в помощь, довольно толковый и простой учебник

http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/opengl/opengl1.html

куб - это 6 граней, каждая из которых состоит из 2 треугольников
у каждого треугольника свои координаты

чтобы нарисовать куб вы можете

1. отрисовать 12 треугольников со своими координатами
2. отрисовать 1 треугольник, но каждый раз применяя к его 3м вершинам матрицы трансформации, т.е. по сути перемещая треугольник в нужное положение - на выходе всё равно это будет как бы отрисовка 12 треугольников

> Смотрел этот туториал и понял что нет какой то определённой функции
> для работы 3х мерным пространством

ну в общем так и есть :) с оговорками

1. у вас есть модель объекта из файла (в самом простом случае - набор треугольников (т.е. координат [x, y, z] для 3 точек)) или вы его создадите "вручную" или сгенерируете по какому-то алгоритму
2. чтобы переместить куда-то в пространстве эту модель, повернуть ее, растянуть и т.д. вы каждую точку треугольников умножите на матрицу преобразования и получите новую точку

вернее так - вы вычислите эту матрицу, а видеокарта уже сделает всю остальную работу

Comment: а если создавать плоскости с помощью GL_QUADS или он тоже состоит из треугольников?

Comment: В качестве дополнения к данному ответу : могу посоветовать еще следующий сайт - https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/OpenGL/index.php  Достаточно хорошие туториалы step by step по SDL и OpenGL

Comment: @Илья Дударь, если я не забыл еще, то всего лишь говорит как идентифицировать вершины - т.е. смотрите допустим у нас есть 4 вершины [1], [2], [3], [4], - я могу из них составить треугольники и массив вершин будет такой [1], [2], [3], [1], [3], [4] и использовать GL_TRIANGLES, а могу [1], [2], [3], [4] и использовать GL_QUADS - в конечном итоге все равно будут полигоны (треугольники), просто во втором случае массив вершин меньше места занимает :) но не все можно так "ужать". В Direct3D вроде этого вообще нет - избыточно.

Comment: Т.е. эти ключи GL_QUADS, GL_TRIANGLES и т.д. всего лишь говорят как идентифицировать вершины в массиве вершин, т.е. как из вершин составлять треугольники

Comment: последний коммент слегка не точен, есть еще точки и линии, т.е. на выходе могут быть не только треугольники